# Slicer - Change Display Values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI, I have a slicer at the top of my report.  It is displaying three values:  "Brand A, Brand B, Brand C", which is expected as these are the values in the database.  There is a request that I change these to:

- Brand A to Apple
- Brand B to Banana
- Brand C to Crab

I know we can change the values in the database to reflect this, but the request has been to change these via Power BI because my manager states "Aren't you able to change the labels in Power BI so the database team doesn't have to re-do it?  I seem to recall that was in the online class we took."  This might be true, but for the life of me, I cannot seem to find how to change what is displayed in the slicer via Power BI without changing the values in the database.  [image: Slicer Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything stopping you from creating a new column in Power BI?

A simple switch statement will let you rename whichever value to whatever you want, and preserve the slicer functionality with the new column.

Say I have a table with people named "ABC" "DEF" and "GHI," all I need to do is create a new column that "switches" those values with ones I designate.

```
Person (New Column) = 
SWITCH(
    Table1[Person],
     "ABC", "Apple",
    "DEF", "Diamond",
    "GHI", "Guava"
)
```

Then I can throw it into a slicer and I'm done.

[image]

[image]

The Power BI forums are a great resource, I think you'll find a lot of great info there.

https://community.powerbi.com/

Comment: As an aside, for some unknown reason, I cannot create an account for Power BI community.  I have tried a couple times and working with Microsoft as to why I am unable to create an account, as it isn't as simple as a username / password, but I need organization account tied to an azure portal account and it isn't working just yet.

Comment: Ah right. I've been working in companies so long & have used SSO that I forget the initial struggle I had signing up for any of these microsoft forums.